# Every algebraic subgroup of an algebraic group is closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to show that every algebraic subgroup of an algebraic group is closed.

If $H$ is an algebraic subgroup of $G$, then so is a subvariety of $G$. Hence, $H$ is locally closed in $G$ and equivalently it is open in its closure $\bar{H}$. $\bar{H}$ is also an algebraic group. Clearly $H \subset \bar{H}$, but how should I show the reverse?

Comment: As a side note -- it seems you have never accepted an answer on a question you've asked, or indicated that these answers were unsatisfactory for some reason. This is bad form.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: Honestly, I didn't know this option, namely, accepting the answer. I have recently noticed, and since then I have posted only two questions and for the previous one, I didn't understand the hint( still thinking about the given hint). However, your answer was helpful and I've just accepted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the basic idea: an open subgroup is always closed, since it is the complement of the union of its nontrivial cosets. Thus, $H$ is closed in $\overline{H}$, which implies that $H$ is closed in $G$.

Comment: would you please explain the "complement of the union of its nontrivial cosets" a little more?